# HP ProCurve: Iterface X is Link Down (errno 365)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, power-supply

In my Home Environment im Using a Windows Server 2012 R2 datacenter (received from dreamspark) to manage my "home-domain". My server has 4 physical network connections, used like this:

- Nic 1 and Nic 2 are "grouped" (link aggregation / teaming) to Serve all Virtual Machines
- Nic 3 is the VPN Interface.
- Nic 4 serves as "major" connection for the hyperv-host.

Every NIC is connected to an HP Pro Curve Managed switch.

When i copy a "big" file to one of the VMs using the teamed connection, the copy speed is frequently dropping to "0 byte/s" for about 3-5 seconds:

[image]

I checked the logs of the switch and noted, that this exactly happens, when one of the links (of the teamed NICs) is going down:

```
1  Info Apr 08 20:34:59 SNTP Send failed - errno 365 
2  Info Apr 08 20:35:32 NIM Interface 2 is Link Down 
3  Info Apr 08 20:35:35 NIM Interface 2 is Link Up 
4  Info Apr 08 20:36:08 SNTP Send failed - errno 365 
5  Info Apr 08 20:36:31 NIM Interface 2 is Link Down 
6  Info Apr 08 20:36:34 NIM Interface 2 is Link Up
```

This only happens, when I copy a large amount of data. When sitting in Idle mode, i frequently see the 365 errors:

```
9  Info Apr 08 20:37:17 SNTP Send failed - errno 365 
10  Info Apr 08 20:38:26 SNTP Send failed - errno 365 
11  Info Apr 08 20:39:35 SNTP Send failed - errno 365 
12  Info Apr 08 20:40:44 SNTP Send failed - errno 365 
13  Info Apr 08 20:41:53 SNTP Send failed - errno 365
```

The Servers Hardware looks like:

- AMD FX-8320
- 16GB-Kit G.Skill RipJaws-X PC3L-14900U CL9
- 2* 400 GB Samsung HDD
- 2* 1000 GB Samsung HDD
- 2* 3000 GB Toshiba HDD
- 3* 1000 Mbit Realtek-NICs
- 1* 1000 Mbit Realtek-Nic (onboard)

I have to admit that the power supply is "only" a (left over) 450 Watt version.

Could it be possible that the above setup is exceeding the 450 Watt supplied by the power source and therefore starts to fail under load?

---

On more testing: Disableing the remaining Network Cards / or VMs does not change anything. Only disabling the teamed adapters and us them independent resolves it. So there seems to be a configuration problem rather than power problem?